# What are thin-core and fat-core processors

Tags: terminology, computer-architecture, parallel-computing

I am reading a paper called *Back to Thin-Core Massively
Parallel Processors* by Ami Marowka (*Computer*, 44(12):49–54, 2011; [IEEE Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5765903/)).

However I have a question about the title of the article: what does "thin core" (and for that matter, "fat core") mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Thin-core* is a simple processing unit, slower with less registers, for example GPU core or small, low-energy core.
*Fat-core* is full-fledged CPU core. The mobile version of CPU is still *fat-core*

From article:

> The IBM Blue Gene/P supercomputer (1 Pflop) is an example of a contemporary large-scale system design (294,912 processors) based on a many-thin (850 MHz, 1 Gbyte) processing-core approach.

Comment: The PowerPC 450 in the Blue Gene/P would appear to be (assuming similarity to PPC 440), dual issue out-of-order with a 7-stage pipeline. This is not comparable even to a Cortex M4 (higher end of M) 3-stage scalar in-order; thin is clearly relative. Also a GPU "core" is more a vector lane than a core.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton I agree with your comment. The term "thin-core" itself is not well defined, I wanted to reflect the article and the meaning used there, because I have read it, but I would like to encourage you to give your own answer, it seems that you have in-depth knowledge about internals so you can shed more light on this relative term.